# Setting classpathPrefix option in Karate via CLI

Tags: karate

I'm using the official Karate VSCode extension and there's an option in the extension settings called `karatelabs-karate.run.classpathPrefix` where a comma-separated list of paths can be provided. This works perfectly for `read()`ing files from various places within my project.

How do I set this when running Karate from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

It took a bit of trial and error, but I figured it out.

I'm using jbang to run Karate, so the run command looked something like this in my case:

```bash
$ jbang --cp "./test/karate:.:karate.jar" com.intuit.karate:karate-core:LATEST:all /path/to/test/dir
```

The key is the `--cp` argument, which needs the karate JAR file as well as the additional paths you want on the classpath.

If you're using Karate via Node.js, you might write something like this:

```js
const karate = require('@karatelabs/karate');
karate.jvm.args = `--cp "./test/karate:.:karate.jar"`;
karate.exec(`${process.cwd()}/src`);
```

Notice the line setting `karate.jvm.args` which are passed *first* in the command send to jbang.

Hope this helps someone else who isn't a Java dev day-to-day. :-)

Comment: thanks for sharing ! there is some related information here for those who want to use the command-line: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension/issues/12#issuecomment-1496905787